# Getting the first frame of a GIF image without downloading all the other frames

Tags: java, android, gif

I would like to get a GIF image from the network, but I found that if I download the whole GIF image, it would cause a lot of network traffic.

Can I get only the first frame of a GIF image without downloading all the other frames?

Comment: I'd love to know the reason for down-voting a totally valid question.

Comment: Using library from this link: https://github.com/dragon66/icafe, it would be as easy as one line call: ImageIO.getReader(ImageType.GIF).getFrameAsBufferedImage(InputStream is) or ImageIO.getReader(ImageType.GIF).read(InputStream is). The return type would be a Java BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1):

9 years 6 months later, the perfect time to help out.
This can be accomplished using ImageMagick using the command:

```
magick mogrify -format png *.gif[0]
```

using a console in the directory of the folder containing the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found ready-to-use solution, but you can do this way (it'll lead to some "low-level" tricks):

Following [wiki about GIFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF), animated gif files can be splitted into frames, and end of frame can be easily recognized. So, you'll need to read GIF header, screen information, information about animation into buffer, download first frame and append information like GIF is ended ("3B" following wiki article). And, if you copy this data into separate bufer, you'll be able to continue whole file downloading without re-downloading first frame.

Also you can edit header information to format first frame into static gif.