# Getting the first frame of GIF image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib, gif

[Getting the first frame of a GIF image without downloading all the other frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510055/getting-the-first-frame-of-a-gif-image-without-downloading-all-the-other-frames)

↑ This thread is almost the same question that I want to know.
But in my case, I am using Python 3.6 and urllib.

```
import urllib
import requests

img_file = urllib.request.urlopen(img_url, timeout=10)

f = open('/img/' + img_name, 'wb')
f.write(img_file.read())
f.close()
```

I am using this code to get image files. But for the GIF or moving jpg(GIF with a jpg file extension) files, it takes too much time to download.

Is there any way to download only the first frame of the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to write the whole thing for you, which would involve parsing the binary contents of the GIF file, but here's an example of incrementally downloading a file using the popular third-party [requests module](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) (using information in this [section](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) of its documentation). Hopefully this will give you a good start point.

```
import requests

img_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif'
#img_filename = 'test.gif'

response = requests.get(img_url, stream=True)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Error:', response.status_code)
else:
    header = response.raw.read(6)
    print(header)  # b'GIF89a'

#    # Download whole file in chunks and save locally.
#    with open(img_filename, 'wb') as f:
#        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
#            f.write(chunk)

print('done')
```

Comment: Just adding to the answer: [here](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load) I\`ve got a nice little library able to read separate frames from GIF images, with a Python usage example.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: If I'm not mistaken, your library looks like it expects a fully-downloaded file to be available and I think the point of this question is to avoid downloading whole thing just to get the first frame. That said, the OP may be able to read your C source code to help figure-out how the parse the file being downloaded incrementally.

Comment: It doesn`t. Quoting the docs: > Partial GIFs are also supported, but only at a granularity of one frame.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: In the [Python usage example](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load) section the code does a `file = open(file, "rb")` and then reads the contents of the entire file in the subsequent `GIF_Load(file.read(), size, ...)` call, so it's unclear how it could be used in an incremental fashion — how does one know the size one frame's worth of data? If you have an answer that can do what's needed for this question, please post it.

Comment: There is no way to know the compressed frame size before reading the GIF data, so the only simple way is to read the next several (kilo)bytes then try to load the GIF, and repeat if no image has been produced.

Answer (score 2):

Posting my answer as advised by @martineau.

1. Build the GIF library as shown [here](https://github.com/hidefromkgb/gif_load#python-usage-example)
2. Execute the code below and wait for `result.png` to be written to disk:

```py
from PIL import Image
from platform import system
from ctypes import string_at, Structure, c_long as cl, c_ubyte, \
                   py_object, pointer, POINTER as PT, CFUNCTYPE, CDLL
import requests

class GIF_WHDR(Structure): _fields_ = \
   [("xdim", cl), ("ydim", cl), ("clrs", cl), ("bkgd", cl),
    ("tran", cl), ("intr", cl), ("mode", cl), ("frxd", cl), ("fryd", cl),
    ("frxo", cl), ("fryo", cl), ("time", cl), ("ifrm", cl), ("nfrm", cl),
    ("bptr", PT(c_ubyte)), ("cpal", PT(c_ubyte))]

def GIF_Load(lgif, file, size):
    def WriteFunc(d, w):
        list = d.contents.value
        if (len(list) == 0):
            list.append(Image.frombytes("L", (w[0].frxd, w[0].fryd),
                              string_at(w[0].bptr, w[0].frxd * w[0].fryd)))
            list[0].putpalette(string_at(w[0].cpal, w[0].clrs * 3))
    list = []
    lgif.GIF_Load(file, size,
                  CFUNCTYPE(None, PT(py_object), PT(GIF_WHDR))(WriteFunc),
                  None, pointer(py_object(list)), 0)
    return list

chunk = 32768
img = "wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif"

lgif = CDLL(("%s.so", "%s.dll")[system() == "Windows"] % "./gif_load")

size = -1
file = b""
response = requests.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/" + img, stream = True)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Error:', response.status_code)
else:
    while size < len(file):
        size = len(file)
        file += response.raw.read(chunk)
        list = GIF_Load(lgif, file, len(file))
        if (len(list) == 1):
            list[0].save("result.png")
            break
    print("Read %d bytes\n" % len(file))
```

Keep in mind though that this is just an illustrational example; it does not support many things present in modern-day GIFs like interlacing and transparency. For a fully compliant version please refer to the example from [1].